# opencart 2.1.0.1 bootstrap 3.3.5 full width dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

I'm trying to get the dropdown full width. I have tried over riding the min-width of .dropdown-menu with min-width:auto and width: 100% but the dropdown then shrinks to the width of the parent li.

I can set a value for .dropdown-menu, 600px for example, which works, but I cannot get it to be full width.

site in development http://192.185.157.130/~devo/spiritbird/

cheers

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set the min-width to an actual number.

```
.dropdown-menu {min-width: 320px;}
```

It looks like it is lining up correctly with that CSS and it works perfectly once the screen goes smaller for responsiveness.

Comment: sure, I tried that, all that happens is the dropdown assumes the min width but wont go the full 100%, even if I set width to 100% :-